# Methods and attributes do not show when dot is pressed (intellisense)

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, pylance

Yesterday I upgraded from `3.11` to python `3.12`.
The editor that i use is `VScode`.

When i use standard patterns with matplotlib (from the official docs), the intellisense does not recognise the types and therefore pressing the dot fails to expose the methods and attributes.

Here is reproducible code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

fruits = ['apple', 'blueberry', 'cherry', 'orange']
counts = [40, 100, 30, 55]
colours = ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'orange']

ax.bar(fruits, counts, label=colours, color=colours)

ax.set_ylabel('fruit supply')
ax.set_title('Fruit supply by kind and color')
ax.legend(title='Fruit color')

plt.show()
```

If i **explicitly typehint**, then it works. But this is very clunky and seems broken.

i now have to do this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure    # added this
from matplotlib.axes import Axes        # added this

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig: Figure                             # added this
ax: Axes                                # added this

fruits = ['apple', 'blueberry', 'cherry', 'orange']
counts = [40, 100, 30, 55]
colours = ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'orange']

ax.bar(fruits, counts, label=colours, color=colours)

ax.set_ylabel('fruit supply')
ax.set_title('Fruit supply by kind and color')
ax.legend(title='Fruit color')

plt.show()
```

I have never had this issue with earlier versions of python as far as i can recall.

How to fix this such that i do not have to explicitly typehint the `fig` and `ax` ?

Comment: It does happen that there is no intellisense after switching to python 3.12, I've [submitted it to developer in github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/22376) for you

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT.  thanks for submitting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see Intellisense after `ax.` in either version of Python. The reason is that `plt.subplots` in matplotlib 3.8.0 returns `tuple[Figure, Any]`, so Pylance doesn't know the type of `ax`. Matplotlib 3.8.0 added inline types which Pylance trusts because the lib is `py.typed`.

Maybe you are using different matplotlib versions in addition to different Python versions? If I install matplotlib 3.7.3 instead of 3.8.0 (regardless of Python version), then Pylance uses its bundled matplotlib stubs and treats `ax` as an `Axes` object.

Comment: I can see intellisense when using python 3.11.0

Comment: so the workaround is to use this: `from matplotlib.axes import Axes`, and explicitly typehint to circumvent the `Any` but it is rather clunky and undesirable.

Comment: If the issue is that you don't get IntelliSense here when using matplotlib 3.8.0, then Pylance is behaving correctly. And yes, adding an explicit annotation on `ax` is a reasonable workaround. You don't need to annotate `fig` because the annotation on `subplots` tells Pylance that the first element of the returned tuple is a `Figure` object. I'd recommend filing an issue in the [matplotlib repo](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues) and asking them to improve the return type of `subplots`.

Comment: I just noticed that there's a matplotlib issue on this: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/27025